# jBPM 6 process tutorial for eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jbpm

I am looking at the [jBPM user guide](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/) and try to create a custom process to start playing. I am trying for example to setup a process which starts with a signal event caused by another application's message. While my intuition says this should be something trivial, I cannot find such an example. The [jBPM documentation on events](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/jBPMBPMN2.html#d0e3107) is not very verbose and is not accompanied by any examples. Moreover, the [jBPM eclipse plugin](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/jBPMEclipseJBPM.html) documentation does not provide any examples of process building and the [Eclipse BPMN2.0 modeller documentation](http://eclipse.org/bpmn2-modeler/documentation.php) provides only broken links.

Could you suggest any tutorials on jBPM process design using either one of the respective eclipse plugins (jBPM eclipse plugin or BPMN 2.0 modeller) from a developer's perspective?

Comment: Since I can see that others are interested in this question too, I want to add that I have not yet found any proper tutorial. However, I started working by following the examples contained in the [git repository](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/tree/master/jbpm-examples). jBPM seems to lack seriously on documentation...

Answer (score 1):

There are two books that might help you: jbpm5 and jbpm6 developer guides. You can also look into the jbpm-bpmn2 module in the git repository that's where all the bpmn2 constructs are tested. After all the best doc is the source code and the tests :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was hoping that red hat could be a little more supportive. Buying a book is always an option but still, I would expect them to provide better guidance.